# How to call image choosen from dialog box by specific function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I want to implement the image processing system in python and I choose the image from a dialog box by specific function in my tkinter frame. Now I don't know how to call the image in other function to process the image.

Here is the code of the function that opens the image from the dialog box: (Package is my frame with title and color background)

```py
def Open(self):
            global tk_image

            filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='path of my dataset')

            img2 = Image.open(filename)
            label4 = Label(Package)
            label4.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
            label4.configure(image=label4.tk_image)
            label4.pack()
```

After the above function, I want to define the processing function to process the image and use img2 from the above function:

```py
def Process(self):
...
```

Comment: Is this about variable naming or is there something more you need help with ? I'm not sure to fully understand the question.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing what you want? Are you familiar with how to create attributes on a class?